# Sitecore: All Indexes are not listed in Index manager

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8

I'm using `Solr` for all `indexing`, so I created all the indexes in solr and enabled all required solr related configs, but when I came to build the index from index manager , I can only see

```
sitecore_core_index
sitecore_master_index
sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master
sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master
sitecore_testing_index
sitecore_suggested_test_index
sitecore_fxm_master_index
sitecore_list_index
social_messages_master
```

I built only these. And if I try to search from web data base, i am not getting any results.

In the default sitecore installation I can see 16 indexes folder inside Data=>Indexes, so where are the rest?
How to Build those?

Or is this what is to be expected?

Comment: You are missing the web related indexes as sitecore_web_index, .. Something must be wrong with your config, but without info it's hard to tell what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if there is `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web.config` in your `App_Config/Include` folder. It must NOT have `.example` extension after the name above. This file contains definition of `sitecore_web_index`.

You can check `http://localhost/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` on the default sitecore installation to see which config files contain other missing indexes (there will be `patch:source` information for every node). Then you can check if those files are included in your solution.

Comment: Oh For my case All the web related solr file were disabled.
Enabled and showing all the web indexes.

Thanks Marek

Comment: One thing I would like to ask here..According to Sitecore's official documentation https://doc.sitecore.net//~/media/9D15F16ED76244CF8001EB030037F49F.ashx?la=en 
there are expecting to disable all web related solr configs for CM server and we need to maintain web db in connection string also. Will it cause any problems when access the website from CM?

Comment: It's incorrect approach to disable `web` related solr configs on CM server. In fact, CM server is the only server which should update all the indexes when running sitecore with solr. CD servers should never update solr indexes. All the indexing strategies on CD servers should be changed to `manual`. And CM server must do all the updates. So the answer is **never disable web related solr configs on CM server**.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in Sitecore 8 instances migrated from 6.X versions the old Lucene indexes (which have not been migrated to the new Lucene format) are not listed in the `Rebuild Index` section from the Developer tab. In order to see the indexes you need to go to `Control Panel > Rebuilt Search Indexes`

[image]

Comment: This is a nice information
For my case those web related indexes were disabled.

Comment: This  option is not visible in Sitecore  9